# Generate number combinations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations

I have been asked to help with writing a simple number generation script. The script should take an array of numbers from 1 to 9 as input. It should then calculate and output all the possible 3-number combinations in a output array.

Here's [a link](http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/combination-permutation-tools/combination-generator/) to a site that generates and outputs the numbers exactly as we want our script to do.

Thanks.

Comment: So have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working now with the following code:

```
for(var a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    for(var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
        for(var c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            var combination = a + '' + b + '' + c;
            if(checkCode(parseInt(combination))) {
                console.log("Password is: + combination)
            }
        }
    }
}
```